# How to split elements of a pandas series and put them into JSON format?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a pandas series object S, some elements are name-value pairs, like 
    a-12 
    b-23 
    c-42 
    d-25 
    ...

some are just 
    a 
    b 
    c 
    d 
    ....

so on, what I need to do is to get this into Json format like:

```
{Name:a,Value:12}
{Name:b,Value:23}
{Name:c,Value:42}
{Name:d,Value:25}
...
```

If only a, b, c, d, not pairs, Values is NaN.

I used str.split("-") function to separate the pairs, for non pairs this would produce NaN for the value part.

I wonder if I can put them together like

```
result=[{"Name": S.str.split("-").str.get(0),"Value": S.str.split("-").str.get(1)}]
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I think you're pretty close, you could  would write it as a list comprehension like

```
result = [{"Name": n, "Value": v} for n, v in zip(S.str.split("-").str.get(0),
                                                  S.str.split("-").str.get(1))]
```

Although it might be a little nicer to use a regex to parse the string:

```
result = [{"Name": n, "Value": v} for n, v in S.str.extract("(\w)-?(\d+)?").values]
```